# Why am I getting a HTTP Connectivity error on Solr cloud?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I created a collection(say test_collection) on a Solr cloud instance using the Solr admin tool with a custom configset.

So write operations can be performed on this server are being carried out via the following service:

```
https://servername:port/solr/test_collection/update?commit=true
```

The following service is used by a middleware(Mulesoft) to write records to Solr in batches of 50 records.

However every time a write is performed, all records get loaded in Solr, except for a batch of 50 records which fail with the following exception:

```
"errortype": "HTTP:CONNECTIVITY",
 "errormessage": "HTTP POST on resource 'https://servername:port/solr/test_collection/update' failed: 
 Remotely closed."
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the Solr log? There might be a malformed update that includes a non-numeric value for a numeric field or something similar.

Comment: No the similar request is successful after trying in Postman separately.

Comment: So what happens in the Solr log (if you put it in DEBUG or INFO mode under Logging in the admin panel, you'll see all requests being made) for that request when it fails? Is it the same batch that fails each time? Remember that postman and MuleSoft might do different processing / escaping of the data, which means that it may still be the content in the request that causes the issue.